# Different color of Overscroll indicator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, overscroll

Is it possible to have a different `color` for the top and bottom `Overscroll` indicator of a `ListView`?

I have the background of the `ListView` a color gradient and want it the top `Overscroll` indicator to match the top of the gradient and the bottom indicator to match the bottom of the gradient.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `ListView` with a `GlowingOverscrollIndicator` and set its `color` parameter. For changing the color for the top and bottom, you can add a listener to the scroll controller of the `ListView`.

```
 var _color = Colors.blue;

  _listener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      // bottom
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.red;
      });
    }
    if (_scrollController.offset <=
            _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      // top
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.blue;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_listener);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
        axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
        color: _color,
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 30,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('$index'),
            );
          },
        ),
    ));
  }
```

Result:

[image: res]

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but what should I add as _scrollController?

Comment: Just add this to your widget's state: var _scrollController = new ScrollController(); @Gvarph